# Как изменить значение нескольких тегов в xml-файле?

Tags: c#, xml

Имеется XML-файл, как изменить несколько значений тега "newval"?
Пытался таким образом, но ничего не вышло.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <root>
      <saveparam>
        <idx>PRESSURE</idx>
        <newval>3.01</newval>
      </saveparam>
      <saveparam>
        <idx>TEMPERATURE</idx>
        <newval>38.43</newval>
      </saveparam>
      <saveparam>
        <idx>COUNT</idx>
        <newval>5</newval>
      </saveparam>
      <saveparam>
        <idx>FLOW_R</idx>
        <newval>150.124</newval>
      </saveparam>
      <saveparam>
        <idx>FLOW_N</idx>
        <newval>0.000</newval>
      </saveparam>
      <saveparam>
        <idx>RATE</idx>
        <newval>10</newval>
      </saveparam>
    </root>
</config>
```

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load("C:/stack.xml");

XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("//root"))
{
    string value = nav.GetAttribute("idx", "");
    if (value == "PRESSURE")
    {
        nav.MoveToFollowing("newval", "");
        nav.SetValue("10");
    }
    if (value == "TEMPERATURE")
    {
        nav.MoveToFollowing("newval", "");
        nav.SetValue("45");
    }
    if (value == "COUNT")
    {
        nav.MoveToFollowing("newval", "");
        nav.SetValue("3");
    }
}
document.Save("C://stack.xml");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используя путь `//root` вы получаете, как неудивительно, элементы с именем `root`. То есть один-единственный элемент. А вам нужно пройтись по нескольким элементам `saveparam`. Для этого используем путь `//root/saveparam` или `//saveparam` (самый короткий) или `/config/root/saveparam` (самый быстрый). Я бы использовал последний, так как использование `//` (descendants) на больших документах может работать катастрофически медленно.

`GetAttribute` возвращает **атрибут**. В вашем документе **нет ни одного атрибута**! Учите формат xml и другие форматы данных (json, csv, yaml и пр.)! Потому что без этого никак! Потому что stackoverflow наводнён однотипными вопросами по парсингу xml (и других текстовых форматов), в которых вопрошающие путают элементарные понятия.

```
foreach (XPathNavigator nav in navigator.Select("/config/root/saveparam"))
{
    string idx = nav.SelectSingleNode("idx").Value;

    if (idx == "PRESSURE")
    {
        nav.MoveToFollowing("newval", "");
        nav.SetValue("10");
    }
    if (idx == "TEMPERATURE")
    {
        nav.MoveToFollowing("newval", "");
        nav.SetValue("45");
    }
    if (idx == "COUNT")
    {
        nav.MoveToFollowing("newval", "");
        nav.SetValue("3");
    }
}
```

Это рабочий код с минимальными изменениями.